# Which type of float to use in swift OpenGL?

Tags: ios, opengl, swift

Which type of float am I supposed to use for vertex data? There are a bunch to choose from. Glfloat, float, float32, etc.

Comment: they will all be the same (typedefed as each other) most of the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS GPU hardware works best with single-precision floating point data. Moreover, many of the higher level libraries (e.g. GLKit, SceneKit) use data structures containing 32-bit floats for vectors, matrices, and the like.

As for which type name to use, remember that Swift doesn't do automatic type conversion. So where in C you could get away with using `float` values in your code and passing them to OpenGL APIs, in Swift you'd have to implicitly convert them to the type(s) used by the API (with `GLfloat(value)`). It's probably best to just use `GLfloat` for your own data so you don't have to insert that conversion.

Even if you're developing only for Apple platforms (since you're using Swift), using `GLfloat` also ensures that you're using whatever data type is required by the OpenGL specification — if you use another type name that happens to specify the same data size/format today, you're relying on that name happening to mean the same thing in the future. (Granted, these particular Swift data types don't seem all that likely to change, but in general it's best to rely on an explicit API contract rather than an implicit match.)

Comment: Indeed, on iOS there's a type: `CGFloat` that some sample software written by Apple uses... if you target a 64-bit version of iOS this type is 64-bit double-precision otherwise it is 32-bit single-precision. Apple themselves assumed that the type was always going to be single-precision 32-bit when they wrote their sample code. Needless to say, OpenGL ES doesn't behave consistently if you pass a pointer to a `CGFloat` to a function that expects a `GLfloat` :P

Answer (score 0):

For OpenGL, you should use the OpenGL data types - `GLfloat` in this case, as they are guaranteed to be the correct types used by the the GL implementation on every platform. In practice, a `GLfloat` will be a 32 bit single precision floating point format in virtually all cases.